# How to Convert String date and time to Regular date and time in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, datetime, string

I wanna convert String date and time to Apex date and time.

```
2016-12-23T07:26:33+0000 => DateTime Of apex.
```

How to convert ?

Comment: You can use this link to set your date into APEX DATETIME : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

Comment: Maybe the parse method from the link put by HSdev should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think de-serializing it to a DateTime class should work fine.

`System.debug(JSON.deserialize('"2016-12-23T07:26:33+0000"', DateTime.class));`

Just make sure that the date is enclosed in double quotes i.e `"<DATE>"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
String dateTimeInString = '2016-12-23T07:26:33+0000';

DateTime acceptableDateTime = DateTime.Valueof(dateTimeInString.replace('T', ' '));
```